# SwiftUI Mismatching Types When Returning View

Tags: swiftui

Why is it in SwiftUI that the following if-else check works as expected but the ?: syntax give errors:

THIS WORKS:

```
if value == true {
    Text("2")
} else {
    EmptyView()
}
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK:

```
return value ? Text("S") : EmptyView()
```

##### Error Message:

> Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'Text' and 'EmptyView'

Comment: It's similar to the behavior of the binary operators: Both *arguments* must be the same type.

Comment: But in if/else condition the return types are not of the same type. One if Text and the other is EmptyView.

Comment: If/else works because of ViewBuilder handles it.

Comment: `if - else` doesn't require a *return value*, it belongs to the enclosing view which allows different types due to the `ViewBuilder` attribute .

Comment: Definitely read up on ViewBuilder. Once you understand it, your question will be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this if-else expression is evaluated, the type of the result is

```
_ConditionalContent<Text, EmptyView>
```

So even if only the `Text` will be displayed in the end, the view's type contains both, the `Text` and the `EmptyView`. This happens implicitly. That's why it's hard to grasp. Any SwiftUI view uses a `ViewBuilder` for its body, that's where the magic happens.

The advantage of this approach is that no matter how your if-condition evaluates (whether it's going to show a `Text` or an `EmptyView`), the type of the resulting view will always be the same – which is a requirement of the `some` keyword used for the body's return type. (That's a difficult concept in itself, see [What’s this “some” in SwiftUI?](https://medium.com/@PhiJay/whats-this-some-in-swiftui-34e2c126d4c4).)

The ternary expression

```
let variable = condition ? a : b
```

doesn't have this magic. It just does what you tell it. Any given variable in Swift must always have a concrete type. If you do not explicitly annotate the type (e.g. `let variable: String = ...`), the Swift compiler automatically *infers* the type by evaluating the right side of the `=`.

When `a` is a `Text` and `b` is a `Text`, it's easy – then `variable` is also a `Text`. But when `a` is a `Text` and `b` is something else (like `EmptyView`), then the compiler can't "decide" what type the `variable` is. It can't be both – and like I said, the magic of wrapping both types in a `CondiationalContent` does not happen for the ternary operator. Thus, you get the error message that there is a mismatch between the two types.